# .htaccess dynamic rewrite not found

Tags: .htaccess

Moving from one dynamic system to another. I have this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/lesson/([0-9]+)?$ /shop/lessons_detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

On entering www.domain.com/lesson/56 (for example), I get a 404, "The requested URL /lesson/56 was not found on this server." error. I instead need it to go to www.domain.com/shop/lessons_detail.php?id=56. I need this dynamically, for the 450+ lessons the system has.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these rules are in an htaccess file, the leading slash (the prefix) in the URI is stripped off so the pattern in your rule must account for that:

```
RewriteRule ^lesson/([0-9]+)?$ /shop/lessons_detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```